# Regex more than one occurrence of a symbol

Tags: php, regex

My regex is as follows `(.*?)add\(\${2,}(.*?)\)`

I want this to validate add($arg1, $agr2)

That is to detect more than 1 occurance of '$' within the add function. I want to return all the text before the add function hence i used `(.*?)` But the `{2,}` part doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: So you want to both extract  and validate? What is the expected output?

Comment: Try this: (.*?)add\((\$.*){2,}(.*?)\)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes. I am using a preg_match so that will give me what i need. But i am unable to check for more than 1 occurrence of the '$' within the add function

Comment: More than 1 argument? `(.*?)\badd\(\$\w+(?:\h*,\h*\$\w+)+\)` https://regex101.com/r/ZO2DiD/1

Comment: @s-s the above doesn't work for the example provided

Comment: You can't return all values captured with a repeated capturing group, you will have to use a regex to validate and get the part before `add` and the part inside parentheses, and then split the arguments string with a comma to get the list of arguments.

Comment: I try in in regex101 and it work: https://regex101.com/r/goBE5v/1/ ,  and the test string: "I want this to validate add($arg1, $agr2)"

Comment: Note it won't let you extract the arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the capturing group to match as least as possible before add.

Then match a single argument starting with a dollar sign and match 1 or more word characters followed by repeating 1 or more times a comma and again an argument.

Note that `(.*?)` will also match an empty string.

```
(.*?)\badd\(\$\w+(?:\h*,\h*\$\w+)+\)
```

**Explanation**

- `(.*?)` Capture group 1, match any char except a newline 0+ times as least as possible
- `\badd` A word boundary, then match `add`
- `\(` Match `(`
- `\$\w+` match `$` and 1+ word characters
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\h*,\h*\$\w+` match a comma between optional horizontal whitespace chars
- `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times
- `\)` Match `)`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zDKFwH/1)